# WCF Authentication with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

I like to secure a wcf service, without passing username password every single call from javascript. I think i can realize it with cookies ? I'm not sure where to start. I like to see code to understand, its says more than words. There are many examples how to make a authentication with .NET, but i'm not sure how the work with relation to javscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do

1. Host WCF in [ASP.NET compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx) mode
2. Deny anonymous access to service uri in Web.Config
3. Implement forms authentication on your web site

Step **1** and **2** will ensure that anonymous access is not granted to WCF service. Step **3** will ensure that with javascript requests any authentication cookies are automatically passed